# Could "advenis quom desideras" mean "arrive (or come) when you want"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Advenis quom desideras

Having 2 verbs, does it make sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would translate this as, "you arrive when you desire". *Advenis* is second person present, not imperative. Note that *quom* is an archaic spelling of classical *cum*.

Being a conjunction, *quom* introduces a second clause, and each clause normally has its own finite verb, so I see no issue there.

Comment: Now that _desidero_ is not in subjunctive mood. It sounds to me more fit as a complaint than a concession